# Almacenar productos que aparecen en un fichero php en un .scv o un .txt separado por comas

Tags: php, html

Muy buenos dias estoy haciendo una tienda virtual con php sin bases de datos y tengo un problema. Como ven tengo una tabla con los productos. Al no haber base de datos he de almacenar estos datos en un fichero como array y no se como hacerlo. Adjunto código. Tambien utilizo sesiones en este caso estoy dentro de la sesion ya osea que ese aspecto no importa. Gracias

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
    <HTML>

    <HEAD>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
        <TITLE>Accés a la sessió com a javi</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <?php
 //session_start();
 $valor = $_SESSION['acces'];
 if ($_SESSION['acces']!="2"){
  //echo "No s'ha iniciat correctament aquesta sessió";
  echo "No heu accedit correctament";
  print '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2;URL=./index.html">';
 }else{
  //echo "Valor de la sessió : $valor<BR>\n";
  //echo "Benvingut a la pàgina privada<BR><BR>\n";
  //echo "<a href=surt.php>Surt de la sessió</a>\n";
 ?>
            <h1 style="text-align:center">Tienda virtual de XiaomisiOsi</h1>
            <html>

            <head>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
                <title>Tienda virtual de XiaomiManda</title>
            </head>

            <body>
                <br>
                <form method='POST' action='r03c.php'>
                    <table border="1" align="center">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td>Imagen del producto</td>
                            <td>Nombre</td>
                            <td>Precio</td>
                            <td>Unidades totales</td>
                            <td>Comprar unidad</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td><img src="imatges/xiaomi.jpg" width="300" style="300" alt=""></td>
                            <td>Xiaomi</td>
                            <td>100</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil1" value="mobil1" />Si<br /></td>                       
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td><img src="imatges/xiaomimi8.jpg" width="300" style="300" alt=""></td>
                            <td>Xiaomimi8</td>
                            <td>200</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil2" value="mobil2" />Si<br /></td>   
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td><img src="imatges/xiaomimix2.jpg" width="300" style="300" alt=""></td>
                            <td>Xiaomimix2</td>
                            <td>300</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="mobil3" value="mobil3" />Si<br /></td>   
                            <tr>
                    </table>
                    <input style="margin-left:650px" type="submit" name="submit" value="Endavant" />
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
            <a style="float:right" href="carrito.php" width="300" style="300" alt="">Acceso carrito</a>
            <BR>

            <BR>
            <BR><a style="float:right" href=surt.php>Surt de la sessió</a>
            <?php
         }
         ?>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: Si solo tienes productos, una linea por producto y separados los campos por el caracter que prefieras.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar las funciones [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) y [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) para trabajar con textos.

Quedaria algo así:

```
function guardar_productos($productos){
    $txt = json_encode($productos);    
    $file = fopen('productos.txt', 'w');    
    fwrite($file, $txt);
    fclose($file);    
}

function cargar_productos(){
    $txt = file_get_contents('productos.txt');
    $productos = json_decode($txt);
    return $productos;
}
```

y llamas a la función correspondiente cuando sea necesario.

el fichero tendría ese aspecto:

```
{
    "productos": [{
            "id": "1",
            "nombre": "cosa 1",
            "color": "rojo",
            "precio": "10"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "nombre": "cosa 2",
            "color": "azul",
            "precio": "55.7"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "nombre": "cosa 3",
            "color": "",
            "precio": "25"
        }
    ]
}
```

Lo puedes validar con alguna herramienta online como https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Pero esto en otro archivo aparte?

Comment: Es indiferente, son funciones php, las puedes añadir al fichero actual o incluirlas desde un archivo aparte. http://php.net/manual/es/function.require.php

Comment: Entonces el fichero txt. como lo preparo en mi caso, del palo la imagen, el nombre, el precio y las unidads totales de cada producto ?

Comment: Edito la respuesta y te pego un ejemplo.